# Mac OS X: Change UID or permissions?

Tags: macos, mac, permissions, user-profiles, uid

I keep the /Users directory on a separate hard drive, /Volumes/Media. I recently upgraded my main drive via a fresh install from Mavericks to Yosemite. I have two users (not including root): seamus (admin) and alex (standard). Seamus is my account. After completing the install, I went to System Preferences and changed my home directory to /Volumes/Media/Users/seamus. Success.

When I did the same for alex, however, I ran into trouble. When I logged in to that account, I couldn't open any of the folders in the home directory. I believe this is because the old Mavericks 'alex' user had UID 503 and my new 'alex' has UID 502.

So the question is, should I go in and try to manually change the permissions for each folder and file in /Volumes/Media/Users/alex to reflect this change? Or can I change the UID in System Preferences to 503 and be set? Or is there another action I should take?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'd start by changing the Yosemite Alex's UID to 503 and see if that gets things working for you.

If you still have trouble, you could do a system-wide search of the Yosemite Alex's UID of 502, like so (as root):

```
# find / -uid 502
```

This should return a list of files from your filesystem still owned by the new 502 alex username, which you can manually chown to the old 503 alex, which is now the new one.  If it turns up a lot of files that you don't want to manually chown, you can throw an

```
 -exec chown alex {} \;
```

on the end of that find and it'll automagically change them all for you.

Hope that helps,
MB